# When to use sub views with Emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Hi guys I plan on having a layout that looks like this:

https://wireframe.cc/uk2C4L

This is my first Ember app and I'm mainly curious when I should take advantage of th sub views with `{{outlet}}`

My question is, should I make the navbar and the entire chat view on one page

Or should I make the navbar and then have a sub view `{{outlet}}` which will be the chat window.

When I click different chat links I don't want the page to refresh I just want the chat window to reload with the chat from the active chat.

This will be my first Ember project and I'm just wondering which way I should lay it out, I read through the Guide which was very helpful but like I said I don't know if I should make the Navbar/Chat on one template or if I should make the navbar and then outlet the chat screen. Any information would be great thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's your first Ember app, it's sortoff like cheating to get us to help you with this. ;P But nevertheless, I think a small demo and some pointers won't hurt.

So think about your app like this, will people want to share chatrooms via a link or just bookmark them and easily fall back in ? If you answer yes, then you should create a route the corresponds to your use case, in this case, you're app will need a router that looks something like this:

```
// router.js
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('friends')
  this.route('users')
  this.route('chatrooms',function(){
    this.route('room',{path:'/:id'})
  })
});
```

your corresponding route templates

```
// templates/chatrooms.hbs
<div class='flex-container'>
  <div class='flex-sidebar'>
    <ul>
    {{#each model as |chatroom|}}
      <li>
        {{#link-to 'chatrooms.room' chatroom}}
          {{chatroom.name}}
        {{/link-to}}
      </li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class='flex-content'>
    {{outlet}}
  </div>
</div>

// templates/chatrooms/room.hbs
<h3>Headline:{{model.name}}</h3>
<hr/>
<ul>
  {{#each model.posts as |post|}}
        <li>{{post.user.name}}:{{post.title}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
<hr/>
{{input value=newMessage placeholder='Type new message here'}}
```

You can have a look at a working example [here](https://ember-twiddle.com/6d678d72d5bb8cd00d894bd346725fcd?openFiles=templates.chatrooms.room.hbs%2C&route=%2Fchatrooms%2F1).

And as your app gets more complex, you can start to componentize some pieces of it, for instance, you could create a component for typing new messages, and a navbar component that contains your user's authentication state. You'll also likely need services that contain this state, which you can then inject into the components.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, is flex-sidebar based off foundation or?

Comment: That's just some out of the box flex, did you have a look at the [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/6d678d72d5bb8cd00d894bd346725fcd?openFiles=styles.app.css%2C&route=%2Fchatrooms%2F1) ? And it there something there you want to know more about ?

Comment: No that gave me a good example of how to use the `{{outlet}}` in the mean-time of waiting for an answer I've basically made the exact same thing, just having issues trying to get http://materializecss.com/ `sideNav` to work.